# Converting $(0, -6, 0)$ from rectangular coordinates to spherical. In particular, finding $\theta$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

My homework asks me to convert the point $(0, -6, 0)$ from rectangular to spherical coordinates. I've found that $\rho = 6$ and $\phi = \frac{\pi}{2}$, but I'm stuck on determining $\theta$.

If $x = \rho sin(\phi)cos(\theta)$ and $y = \rho sin(\phi)sin(\theta)$, then $\theta = arctan(\frac{y}{x})$, but x is zero in this case, and division by zero is undefined. Have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: The value of theta is -pi/2. Theta is defined that way when x is zero and y is negative.

Comment: Visualize the situation. $\theta$ measures the angle from the $z$-axis and you’ve got a point on the $x$-$y$ plane. What might the angle be?

Comment: @amd Do you mean $\phi$ measures the angle from the z-axis? $\theta$ is the angle from the x-axis to the y-axis

Comment: Sorry, I’m used to a different convention for the coordinate names. A similar comment applies: you’re measuring the angle in the $x$-$y$ plane from the positive $x$-axis and you’ve got a point on the negative $y$-axis. Observe, too, that $\tan\theta$ blows up as you approach $\pm\pi/2$ just as $y/x$ blows up as $x\to0$.

Comment: Gotcha, okay. I visualized it and got $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ as the correct answer. Thank you! @amd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Turning my comment into an answer.)

Conversion formulas aside, $\theta$ measures the angle in the $x$-$y$ plane from the positive $x$-axis. The given point is on the negative $y$-axis, so depending on the convention you’re using for $\theta$’s allowed values, $\theta$ is either $-\frac\pi2$ or $\frac{3\pi}2$.